# Passing state from function to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My entire goal was to navigate from a screen while changing states in the screen I am navigating to. I have successfully done that in a minimal working example, however in my overall project, the screen I am navigating to needs to be passed the state through a couple levels.

**I have two examples. In the first example**(You must run the examples in IOS or android, you can see what I need to achieve, everything works as it should. You can move from screen3 to the home page and the states change along with the slider button moving.

**In the second example**, you can see right off the bat I have an error due to my attempt at passing states the same way I do in the original example however there is one more level I need to pass through in this example. You can see by removing line 39 in this demo, it removes the error so obviously I am not passing states correctly. **I need to pass states from Home to Top3 to Slider**

Here is [example 1](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/bottom-stack-page-to-home-while-changing-states) and here is [example 2](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/demo-bugs) while I have also provided some code below that highlights the differences where the error occurs in the two examples.

Any insight at all is appreciated more than you know! Thank you.

Example1 -> you can see I directly render the slider button which causes zero issues.

```
const Home = ({ route }) => {
  const [isVisile, setIsVisible] = React.useState(true);
  const [whichComponentToShow, setComponentToShow] = React.useState("Screen1");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(route.params && route.params.componentToShow) {
      setComponentToShow(route.params.componentToShow);
    }
  }, [route.params]);


  const goToMap = () => {
    setComponentToShow("Screen2");
  }

  const goToList = () => {
    setComponentToShow("Screen1");
  }

  return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1' && <ListHome />}
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen2' && <MapHome />}
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 1}}>
        <Slider
          renderMap={goToMap}
          renderList={goToList}
          active={route.params && route.params.componentToShow==='Screen2'|| false}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}`
```

Example2 -> You can see I render Slider in a file called Top3, I am struggling to pass these states from Home to Top3 to Slider.

```
  const [isVisile, setIsVisible] = React.useState(true);
  const [whichComponentToShow, setComponentToShow] = React.useState("Screen1");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(route.params && route.params.componentToShow) {
      setComponentToShow(route.params.componentToShow);
      goToMap()
    }
  }, [route.params]);


  const goToMap = () => {
    setComponentToShow("Screen2");
  }

  const goToList = () => {
    setComponentToShow("Screen1");
  }

  return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf' ,flex: 1}}>
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen1' && <ListHome />}
      {whichComponentToShow === 'Screen2' && <MapHome />}
      <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 1}}>
        <Top3
          renderMap={goToMap}
          renderList={goToList}
          active={route.params && route.params.componentToShow==='Screen2'|| false}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Top3

```
export default class Top3 extends React.Component {


  goToMap = () => {
    this.props.renderMap();
  };

  goToList = () => {
    this.props.renderList();
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
        <Slider renderMap={this.goToMap.bind(this)}
          renderList={this.goToList.bind(this)}
          active={active}/>
    </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your examples, I think you are not extracting `active` from props properly.
here is the demo working code your example2 code https://snack.expo.dev/4atEkpGVo

here is the sample code for component `Top3`

```
export default class Top3 extends React.Component {


  goToMap = () => {
    this.props.renderMap();
  };

  goToList = () => {
    this.props.renderList();
  };

  render() {
    const {active=false} = this.props;
    return (
        <View>
        <Slider renderMap={this.goToMap.bind(this)}
          renderList={this.goToList.bind(this)}
          active={active}/> 
    </View>

    );
  }
}
```

if you want to share states between multiple screens, then you might want to use global stores like react context api or redux instead of passing states to each screen that would be simple